Absolute continuity of action of compact group
Let $G$ be a Hausdorff compact group acting on a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ and $f:X\to\mathbb C$ be continuous. I'm trying to prove that for every $x\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$ there's a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $y\in U$ implies $|f(gx)-f(gy)|<\epsilon$ for every $g\in G$.
This is a step in the proof that the average of $f$ over $G$ is continuous, and the lecture notes I'm reading state this without justification. I know how to prove this in the case $X=G$ and the group action is multiplication, and in the case where $G$ is sequentially compact, but alas that isn't implied by compactness in general. It seems clear that the strategy is to find an open cover of $G$ then extract a finite subcover, but I'm unable to complete the proof.

Let $x_0 \in X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$.
For every $g \in G$ let $V_g \subseteq X$ and $U_g \subseteq G$ be neighborhoods of $x_0$ and $g$ such that $|f(hx)-f(gx_0)| < \varepsilon/2$ for every $(h,x) \in U_g\times V_g$. Since $G$ is compact there are $g_1,\dots,g_n \in G$ with $G = U_{g_1}\cup \dots \cup U_{g_n}$.
Now let $V := V_{g_1}\cap \dots \cap V_{g_n}$.
Let $g \in G$ and $x \in V$.
Then $g \in U_{g_i}$ for some $i$ and $x \in V \subseteq V_{g_i}$. Therefore
$$|f(gx)-f(g_i x_0)| < \varepsilon/2$$
since $(g,x) \in U_{g_i}\times V_{g_i}$ and
$$|f(g_i x_0) - f(gx_0)| < \varepsilon/2$$
since $(g,x_0) \in U_{g_i}\times V_{g_i}$. Thus
$$|f(gx)-f(gx_0)| \leq |f(gx)-f(g_i x_0)| + |f(g_i x_0) - f(gx_0)| < \varepsilon/2 +\varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon.$$
